# ADO.NET get column header

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using ADO.NET.

I have 2 DataTables:

```
1) dt1  
2) dt2
```

What I like to do is to copy just the header columns from dt1 and populate dt2 with it. Again I just need the column header.

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Clone` the DataTable. Use [`DataTable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method.

```
DataTable dt = dt1.Clone();
```

If you just want to copy the column names and create columns with same name in the other DataTable you can do:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt1.Columns)
{
    dt2.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
}
```

If you just need column names then you can get a `List<string>` instead of a new DataTable. Like:

```
List<string> columnNames = dt1.Columns
                              .Cast<DataColumn>()
                              .Select(r => r.ColumnName)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this return just the column header?

Comment: @NatePet, this will copy all the structure, and columns. **But No Data**